# Internet access only works after turning off and on the local connection

Tags: windows, networking, internet, internet-connection

Every time I turn on the computer, it has no internet access. The network card is connected to a router which broadcasts the internet all over the office LAN. Once I turn off and then on the local connection (or network card), the internet access works.

Rebooting and logging out/in again does not help. **Only** the turning off and on the network card gives me internet access.

Why is that? How do I fix it?

Comment: do you mean enabling and disabling? sounds maybe it's not getting an IP unless you do that but i've no idea why. I'd have thought turning a computer on would cause it to try to get an IP.. Do ipconfig /all Before disabling and enabling your network card. Then again after. See the difference in IPs, report back.

Comment: yeah i mean disabling and enabling. alright i will report

Comment: `route print 0*` may be better, more informative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No solutions found except for the reinstalling Windows.